# Detailed (download) statistics for artifacts of public repositories like maven.org

Tags: java, maven, nexus

In former days project hosting sites like sourceforge.org provided detailled (download) statistics for every project. This was helpful to me as a user for finding projects that are more popular (and therefore more "secure" and futureproof). But I think this was also important for the developers of those projects.

I am new to Maven and have not found any comparable statistics, only the ["Quick Stats" on Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#stats).

Does the Maven concept (and Nexus) provide detailed statistics: how much a specific artifact has been downloaded as a specific type (like jar, pom etc?). If yes, where can I find this (for example for [Hibernate](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Chibernate-core))?

Comment: Too bad the [Maven Central top 10](http://search.maven.org/#stats) isn't very interesting since 7 out of 10 places are occupied by parts/plugins of Maven itself (or Plexus which it uses). I'd like to find stats of top Java libs, [something like in this blog post](http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2012/05/google-guava-shows-strong-growth-in-april/) except up-to-date...

Comment: For an example of a package manager that does display download statistics on a per-package basis, check out npm (Node Package Manager).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you publish artifacts with OSS Sonatype (central Maven repo) there are download statistics available for the artifacts you publish from your account.

Note that it usually updates a few days after each month.

1. Go to  https://oss.sonatype.org
2. Login with the account you publish artifacts with.
3. Click "Central Statistics Repositories".

Reference: Here's a [blog post](https://blog.sonatype.com/2010/12/now-available-central-download-statistics-for-oss-projects/) describing how to access the feature.

Comment: I'm publishing my open source project to Maven Central using Sonatype staging server (https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/) and there you don't get statistics - even though the button is there, it shows you nothing. It is a shame - I would have really liked to know how my project is doing.

Comment: @Guss Maybe there hasn't enough time passed since first publication? Check again, I see stats when I log in to s01.oss.sonatype.org.

Comment: The project was there for at least a couple of years, but now I can see the statistics - maybe it was a temporary error.